# Is it unwise to extend the Airflow TaskGroup class?

Tags: airflow

I'm thinking in terms of DAG persistence, and if this can lead to problems. Like if the serialisation starts to serialise the properties of the Custom TaskGroup class.

I see some benefits of keeping a cleaner code, by extending the TaskGroup and making a custom TaskGroup that, by default, contains some tasks. Then, in the DAG, I can add features to that TaskGroup using functions. These functions can add dependencies to the custom TaskGroup's tasks, which are now properties of the TaskGroup.